# Array out of bounds errors after compiling

Tags: java, arrays

I can't see to figure out why I keep getting the array out of bounds error after I run the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Judge {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a degree of difficulty between 1.2 - 3.8");
    String difficultyString = keyboard.nextLine();
    double difficulty = Double.parseDouble(difficultyString);
    int[] scores = new int[6];
    for(int i = 0; i<scores.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the score of a judge");
        String tempWord = keyboard.nextLine();
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(tempWord);
        scores[i] = temp;
    }
    int low = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(scores[0], scores[1]), Math.min(scores[2], scores[3])),Math.min(scores[4], scores[5])), scores[6]);

    int high = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(scores[0], scores[1]), Math.max(scores[2], scores[3])),Math.max(scores[4], scores[5])), scores[6]);
    int additon = scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2] + scores[3] + scores[4] + scores[5] + scores[6];
    int score = (additon - low) - high;
    double actualScore = (score * difficulty) * 0.6;
    System.out.println("The score of the diver is : " + actualScore);
}
```

}

Just ignore my code. I know it's sloppy and not the easiest way to do it but what am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: You can't access this `scores[6]`. Your array is length 6 meaning the last index is 5.

Comment: Because you're accessing an element that is out of bounds. Is there a particular part of the explicit error message that is confusing you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `scores` arrays has length 6, that mean 0 to 5th index, 6 elements. You are accessing 6th index of it. You have add only up to 5th index like below

```
int additon = scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2] + scores[3] + scores[4] + scores[5];
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays from 0 to 5 but you are tring to get the `scores[6]` its not possible so only the array `indexOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 3):

`int[] scores = new int[6];` means you create **6** elements in the array.

The **6** elements you created are:

```
scores[0] //1st element
scores[1] //2nd element
scores[2] //3rd element
scores[3] //4th element
scores[4] //5th element
scores[5] //6th element
```

Your code mentioned `scores[6]` which is an element that does not exist (out of array bounds).